# AngularFire2 and Firestore dyanamic query: based on the user preferences

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

here is what I want to achieve.

I have users with favorite clubs added (like Liverpool, Barca etc). The number of favorite clubs can vary from 1 - 5 (max 5).

When I need to show fav clubs news, I need to get all the news from firestore which has club name added as a property of the document like this...

```
news: sddf938slsjsf(ID): title: 'news title', club: 'Liverpool'
```

If I knew how many clubs which is fixed in number, I could have - five observable stream based on the each of the fav_clubs (.where('club', '==','Liverpool') and use CombineLatest operator.

But in my case, The number of favorite clubs can vary which is being fetched from user collection -> Tagged_clubs.

I am struggling to find a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your minimal required model (I won't limit to 5 clubs to go faster) :

```
User {
  ID: string;
  favorites: string[];
}

Club {
  ID: string;
}

New {
  club: string;
  title: string;
  content: string;
}
```

Now, let's say you want to get all the news for the favorite clubs of your user.

```
getFavNews(user: User) {
  const calls = [];
  for (let fav of user.favorites) {
    calls.push(this.getNewForClub(fav));
  }
  return forkJoin(calls);
}

getNewForClub(club_ID: string) {
  // Firebase request to get the news about the given club
}
```

With this code, you will need to subscribe to the method, that will return an array of news for the club : `forkJoin` allows you to trigger several requests at once, and your subscription will be executed only when all requests have been made.

That is how I would have done it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this solution and will update this post.

Comment: Thanks it works. But one important point when working with firestore queries - the valueChanges() or snapShopChanges() will not complete. Observable has to be completed to work with forkJoin. I am using take(1) operator to make the observable complete.

Comment: One more query if you could shed some light on : After forkjoin, the result is an array of array [ { }[ ], { }[ ] ] , I want to combine all those item into one single. I cant figure out how to do it :( :(

Comment: I too use the `take` operator to cancel my requests. Do you want to keep the realtime up in your case ?

Comment: About your second issue, you can use `forkJoin(calls).map(arrays: Array<any[]> =>  [].concat.apply([], arrays))`. this will concatenate all of your arrays into one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regarding the requirement, completed observable is okay. But since you asked, how would I do the same if I have real time data coming in.?

Comment: Then you should use the `combineLatest` operator instead of the fork join.